# Fleshing out our tag wiki

Tags: discussion

I noticed there hasn't been any activity in our tag wiki yet, so I went ahead and created one for the "[website" tag](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/website/info). It'd be cool if everyone could help out fleshing this out.

Also, is there any information available about the effectivity of having tag wiki pages filled in? Is it worth maintaining or should we just put down some basic descriptions? Perhaps we could assign a moderator to keep an eye on them and ensure they get filled up when necessary?

Comment: Thanks Rahul. In addition to the wiki, please think about synonyms. I added a couple of synonyms for website.

Comment: @Patrick - any chance of promoting this a bit more? I've just added a couple of wiki entries as I noticed that the front page was looking a little sparse. I'll try and do a few more over the next few days.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, maybe we should target the top 20 tags. I'll put together a list of to-dos when I'm in front of a computer.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken the liberty to post descriptions on the 20 most popular and "empty" tags. I'll continue down the list of empty tag descriptions until I see a stop sign :)

Comment: Nice work. Thanks Benny! I've approved your edits.

Answer (score 2):

And I've added content for [Overflow](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/overflow/info) and [Master-Details](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/master-details/info), which has been accepted.

My formula is, a brief highly visual overview of the kinds of questions and solutions and general trends in solutions, linking to selected questions to dig deeper, ending with a "Creating an XYZ question".

Comment: That's some seriously awesome overkill work there James. Don't you have a day job? ;)