# How to make Tag wiki info more discoverable.

Tags: discussion, design, tag-wiki

I would like tag wiki info content to be more discoverable.  At the moment there is no way to know from the tags page which if any tags have info articles attached.

**UI Tweak needed?**

Do we need a tweak to the stackexchange UI to better promote discovery of the info articles, and if so how?  I'm thinking along the lines of:

- On the tagged questions results pages, a show/hide toggle to show the article *in addition to* the excerpt, above the list of questions.
- Inclusion of tag-wiki info pages in question search results, ***as if they were CW questions***, e.g: "What's covered in [overflow](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overflow) questions?"  This would allow voting (=quality control) favoriting (=promotion) answering (=solicit comment ).

Are there some better suggestions?

**Using Existing Facilities**

If we don't need a tweak, is that because we can use existing features in a better way, and if so how?

**Related Question**

This question is motivated by this one, though coming at it from a different angle:

- [Fleshing out our tag wiki](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/fleshing-out-our-tag-wiki)

---

### Update

- We now have excerpts for the first three pages worth of tags.  Everything with 9 or more questions has one.  Extending that out into less used tags seems to be in 'diminishing returns' territory.
- Three of the tag-wiki-info sections give reasonably visual 'overviews'.  They are [Overflow](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/overflow/info), [Master-Details](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/master-details/info) and [Icons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/icons/info)
- There is a new mechanism for promoting site activity - [Community Ads](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377/community-promotion-ads-2h-2011).  Community ads now exist for tag wiki, but to date none have been upvoted or commented on.

Tag-wiki-info pages remain a somewhat hidden corner of stack-exchange.  On Stack overflow the tag-wiki-info pages are sketchy, and not a patch on what is available on Wikipedia.  Given the community behind the stack-overflow site it's intriguing to speculate whether as vibrant pages could be possible, with a more stack-exchange feel to them, through a change in UX.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly a reasonable suggestion, but I want to be clear about one thing:

The **wiki excerpt** is by far the most important part of the tag wiki. Per [Clay Shirky's Here Comes Everybody](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1594201536):

> “…as long as the experts did nothing (which, on Nupedia, is mostly what they did), nothing happened. In an expert-driven system, an article on asphalt that read “Asphalt is a material used for road coverings” would never appear, even as a stub. So short! So uninformative! Why, anyone could have written that! Which, of course, is one of the principal advantages of Wikipedia. **In a system where anyone is free to get something started, however badly, a short, uninformative article can be the anchor for the good article that will eventually appear. Its very inadequacy motivates people to improve it.**”

I am not opposed to what you are suggesting, but there is a very intentional reason we push so hard to have excellent tag wiki excerpt "stubs" first... and it is why visiting

https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags

and paging around there, it is *very, very* clear which tags have no tag wiki excerpt!