# Community Promotion Ads - 2H 2011

Tags: discussion, promotion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2012](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's Twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (Imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

#### Display and Statistics

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click statistics [here](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/377).

Comment: [Blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) for more background about this and links to example ads for other stackexchange sites.  I asked for this for UX too, to help build awareness.

Comment: Ubuntu, huh. ;-)

Comment: Ubuntu refs removed.

Comment: The roll over text is still place holder by the way. Can we change it to "Come and join us!" or something?

Answer (score 13):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Overflow tag at ux.stackexchane]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Tag-wiki 'icons' at ux.stackexchange]