# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to again reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful doodads and gizmos for UX experts
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1194).

---

### Photoshop file for creating UX-styled ads

> I've created a Photoshop file used to create the 5 below UX-styled ads, which you can [download here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/204960/UX%20ad.psd)
>
> - Rahul

Comment: I included the Photoshop file from Rahul from last thread, assuming that people find it useful. If people feel that was in bad taste or anything, let me know and I'll take it down.

Answer (score 5):

[image: You should follow @StackUX on Twitter.]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Commit to the new Q&A Site for Gamification!]

Answer (score 0):

[image: UXbrella - Q&A for designers who care. Could User Experience do with a better name? Vote here!]

Comment: The idea here is to attract people into the identity/branding discussion through this ad, not to suggest people should vote on Uxbrella or only think about the name of the site.

Comment: In that case this probably needs a rethink (perhaps avoiding mentioning UXBRELLA or using the rainbow branding). On first glance I assumed that this was an advert for the rebrand, not an advert for a discussion about rebranding.

Comment: It needs something to draw the eye and make you say "I have an opinion about this" so you click and go to up or downvote it, though. Any suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: Yes, While I am becoming a fan of the Uxbrella idea, this needs to be discussed more around here before it's something we can promote really. (*How* we get the discussion going about uxbrella though is a different question).

Comment: I updated the image and removed the Uxbrella reference.