# Why were these questions marked as duplicates just because they're old?

Tags: discussion, questions, exact-duplicates

Each of these questions on *Meta UX* were marked as duplicates of the version posted in the subsequent year.

- [Community Promotion Ads - 2012](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626/community-promotion-ads-2012)
- [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/community-promotion-ads-2013)
- [Community Promotion Ads - 2014](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1497/community-promotion-ads-2014)
- [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1764/community-promotion-ads-2015)

Why would an old question be marked as a duplicate of a more current version? Although they're very similar, they aren't duplicates of each other. One of the questions even says "exact duplicate," but they're clearly **different years** of community promotion ads!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's marked as a duplicate because we don't want people submitting suggestions to old posts. But we don't want to remove it because it's useful to see what came before - we want to link people to the most appropriate, canonical (i.e. most preferred) post.

Because we don't want people submitting things to the previous one, each year the old one is marked a Duplicate because it's been superseded by a more relevant link.

We would have to introduce a whole new close reason of 'this has been superceeded by another post' which would only ever be used for things like that, so the cost/benefit of introducing such a thing is not in favour of such a thing.